# Hide specific HTML element if screen is smaller than 767px (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, width, hide

On one of my websites I want to remove a specific HTML element if the screen is smaller than 767px (on mobile devices).

The following piece of HTML is used 9 times on the page:

```
<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>
```

So all 9 pieces of HTML have to be removed only on mobile devices.

I already included the following jQuery file on the website:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
        $('<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>').show();
    }
});
```

However, the code is not working and the pieces of HTML still show up on mobile devices. I know there might be a very easy fix for this particular objective. But after searching the internet for two days I have come across so many different options that actually made me more confused.

Would very much appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't use CSS because only the 'div.price-list__item-desc' with "&nbsp;" inside have to be deleted on mobile. All the other 'div.price-list__item-desc' elements have to remain visible.

Comment: But than why do you use `.hide()` instead of actually `.remove()` - your question makes no sense, and yes, **CSS should be used** for such a task.

Comment: Also `'<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>'` is not a selector.

Comment: Also, using `&nbsp;` as a matching criteria is a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's nothing calling your function.  Use media queries instead.

UPDATE: I added some js to solve your problem.  If you are trying to hide (so the div still takes up space but doesn't show anything) then your question doesn't really make sense.  If you want to remove the div then set display to none.  The js is used to grab the divs that you want

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName('price-list__item-desc')
for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
 
   if (divs[i].innerHTML == "&nbsp;")divs[i].classList.add('hide')
}
```

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) { 

.hide{
display:none;}
}
```

```html
<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">6</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">7</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">8</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">9</div>
```

Comment: I can't use CSS because only the div.price-list__item-desc with "&nbsp;" inside have to be deleted. All the other div.price-list__item-desc have to remain visible.

Comment: snippet updated, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the class 'hide' is not being added at all..

Comment: it works in the snippet. What errors are you getting in console.log

Comment: where are you adding the javascript? Make sure you add the script just before the closing <\body> tag

Comment: I added the code to https://elgaucho.nl/menu/
Can you maybe check it? Didn't add the CSS yet, wanted to see whether the 'hide' class is being added or not

Comment: Added your code to 'menu-distance.js':
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://elgaucho.nl/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/js/menu-distance.js?ver=5.8.3' id='child-theme-script-menu-js'></script>

Comment: YOU ARE ADDING THE SCRIPT IN THE WRONG PLACE.   Make sure you add the script just before the closing <\body> tag

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the silly mistake...

Answer (score 1):

In the first method, when the page `width` changes, the `div.price-list__item-desc` element is hidden or shown using jQuery by controlling the page `width`.

In the method you developed, the *anonymous function* is not run to hide the item when the page changes; you need to use event handler method. In the structure I developed, the `onresize` event is affected when the page width changes. This way I can catch this event when the page width changes.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  window.onresize = function() {  
    console.log(`Width: ${$( window ).width()}`);
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div.price-list__item-desc");
    
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches)
    {
        $('div.price-list__item-desc').removeClass("active");
      
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) 
        {
          if(divs[i].innerHTML === '&nbsp;')
            divs[i].style.display = "none";
          else
            divs[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    else
    {
      $('div.price-list__item-desc').addClass("active");
    }
  }
  
  window.onresize();
});
```

```css
div.price-list__item-desc {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}

.active{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">1</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">2</div>
<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't use CSS because only the div.price-list__item-desc with "&nbsp;" inside have to be deleted. All the other div.price-list__item-desc have to remain visible.
However, on line 3 of you js code I get the error "Unexpected console statement. [no console]"

Comment: Also, the JS code you provided hides all the 'div.price-list__item-desc' elements. I only need to delete the '<div class="price-list__item-desc">&nbsp;</div>' elements

Comment: Still not working.. getting the following error from Google Chrome DevTools: 'Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function'

Comment: You have to add jquery cdn reference to html file. `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have done that already..

Comment: @Tyrion Paste the code above, which I have updated to the HTML file. Most likely you are using the script before the jquery definition.

Comment: Thank you very much.. added the code just before </body> tag and it worked! Helped me out a lot here.

Comment: @Tyrion If you look at the previous edit I reverted, first the jQuery cdn reference is defined, then the script is defined. Same thing as getting this script on the line before </body>.

Comment: That is true, thank you very much